# Submit an angular form programmatically and still get HTML5 validation errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, forms, validation

I have a save button at the top of my page, a search form, then my form where I can edit an item. It looks something like this:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="save()">Save</button>

<form name="searchForm" ng-submit="search()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="criteria" />
</form>

<form name="saveForm" ng-submit="save()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="item.field" required />
</form>
```

I want my save button to submit the save form instead of calling `save()` directly so if the required field is empty, the browser will prompt the user to fill it in. How can I submit the form from a button outside the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use HTML5 validation, I'm pretty sure you will have to use a real submit input, and not an angular button.

In theory, you could use the HTML5 'form' attribute on a standard submit input to achieve this effect. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-form. However, you would want to check browser compatibility carefully.

If that doesn't work, I suspect you will have to fall back to putting your submit input inside the form in your markup and then employ "clever" CSS to relocate your button to where you need it on the page.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `form` attribute. That may come in handy some day. Your answer is a good solution, so I marked it as the answer, but I have to support older browsers, so I posted another answer with what I did to get it to work.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I expected. I had to share the form attribute though, just read about it the other week when I was perusing other HTML5 improvements. Some day :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed to support older browsers, I couldn't use Dana's answer. I ended up adding a submit button at the bottom of the page with an id of "saveButton" and then changing the top button to this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('saveButton').click()">
    Save
</button>
```

I know it's not the *Angular* way to do things and I feel dirty doing it, but it works.